# Question referring to minimum value of a expected value.

Tags: probability, expectation

Some exercises have problems regarding direct use of the expected value. But one as follows asks to find the **minimum** expected value, how would I set the input values of integration for such a problem? Example.

> Suppose $X$~$Exp(1)$. Find $E \ min (X,1)$

The general formula for the expected value of a continuous variable is $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }xf(x)dx$ , but i can't see how to enter the values for the proper solution.

ps. Exp is the exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ E\min\{X,1\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \min\{x,1\} f(x) \, dx .$$
where $f(x)$ is the PDF.

Comment: But how do I know what's the minimum value between x and one?  I'm integrating a **function** and suddenly there's the min{x,1} which i can't see how it fits in the integration process.

Comment: You know that $\min\{x,1\} = x$ if $x \le 1$, and $\min\{x,1\} = 1$ if $x \ge 1$.  So the integral becomes $$\int_{-\infty}^1 x f(x) \, dx + \int_{1}^\infty f(x) \, dx .$$

Comment: WOW! Thanks very much Stephen, that was brilliant!!